# Problems viewing/editing a date in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php page that is creating a table from a mysql database. In that table I have an edit button to edit the data and update the mysql database. All is working great except one column that is a date. If I pull the date into a text input it works fine, but I'd prefer this to be a date field ideally to have the calender selector.

When I change the input type to date it doesn't pull the date over - instead it displays dd / mm / yyyy. This is annoying as if I only need to change the other fields and not the date I have to manually add the date again each time I try to update. Could anyone advise how to populate the date box with the date from the mySQL database?

My code (where shipping_date is the affected date):

index.php displaying the table

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM final_view1 WHERE freight = 'Fedex' OR freight = 'DHL' OR freight = 'IBC' ORDER BY shipping_date DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["shipping_date"] . "</td><td>" . $row["freight"]. "</td><td>" . $row["tracking_no"] . "</td><td>" . $row["vendor_name"] . "</td><td>" . $row["receiver"] . "</td><td>" . $row["pieces"] . "</td>
<td>" . $row["days_in_transit"] . "</td><td>" . $row["courier_status"] . "</td><td>" . $row["comments"] . "</td><td align=right><a href='courier_edit.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='button-edit1'>Edit</a>&nbsp
<a href='complete.php?id=".$row['id']."' class='button-complete'>Complete</a></td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>
```

courier_edit.php

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM final_view1 where id='$ID'");
$result->execute();
for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
$id=$row['id'];
?>

<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="courier_edit_db.php<?php echo '?id='.$id; ?>"  enctype="multipart/form-data";">
    <table class="styled-table">
        <tr class="active-row">
            <td><label for="inputPassword">Company</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="freight" required value="<?php echo $row['freight']; ?>"></td>


            <td><label for="inputPassword">Ship date</label></td>
            <td> <input type="date" name="shipping_date" required value="<?php echo $row['shipping_date']; ?>"></td>
```

Comment: Security notice: You're not using the prepared statement correctly in courier_edit.php so it may be subject to SQL injection attacks depending on where ID is sourced. You should use parameters.

Comment: **Warning!!!** Your code is open for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), please use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) preferably with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Most probably HTML's handling of date picker doesn't handle this format. Keep in mind that *native handling* can be browser-dependant, therefore if you want to use date picker and want to make sure it will be valid in all browsers, use some JS library according to libs you already have in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said - "If I pull the date into a text input it works fine" 
What is the date format written there  ? 
to fit your date into your  `<input type="date">`  you need to change the date format,
You need to change the date format to standard date format.

I hope you understand what I want to say , try something similar to this -

```
<input name="any_name" type="date"
value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data["congestart"])) ?>"/>
```